# How to Merge Two Model Serialisers in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I want to merge the results of two models. I have two models as below.
First is Product and the other is ProductChannelListing

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey()
    # has many other fields which I want in the response



class ProductChannelListing(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey()
    channel = models.ForeignKey()
    is_visible = models.BooleanField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

I want the result in the following way.

{
"name": "ABC",
"category": {},
"is_visible": true,
"price":  200,
**
}

I want make the query efficient query such that it should not make so many queries.

Comment: make it nested serializers

Answer (score 0):

```
from .models import Product, ProductChannelListing

class ProductSerializer(model.serializer):
   class Meta:
    model: Product
    fields = '__all__'

class ProductChannelListingSerializer(model.serializer):
   product = ProductSerializer(ready_only=True)
   class Meta:
    model: ProductChannelListing
    fields = '__all__'
```

Do the same for channel also, and u will get all fields visible at one viewpoint with serializer_class as ProductChannelListingSerializer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this will give me the nested objects which I don't want. I want to represent a simple json object with no nested bindings.

Comment: Ok. Then we will use def representation function to get the results in the format we desire. I will share it that way here.